# Use an encoder with an image as a parameter or use predict method

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm using Python 3.7.7. and Tensorflow 2.1.0.

I'm using an encoder from a U-Net network and I've been using the encoder as a function, passing the images as a parameter, to get an output. But now I have found that I can use `predict` method:

```
support_set_embeddings = encoder(X_train)
support_set_embeddings_predict = encoder(X_train)

print("Embeddings type: ", type(support_set_embeddings))
print("Embeddings predict type: ", type(support_set_embeddings_predict))
print("Support set embeddings shape: ", support_set_embeddings.shape)
print("Embeddings predict shape: ", support_set_embeddings_predict.shape)
```

With this output:

```
Embeddings type:  <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor'>
Embeddings predict type:  <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor'>
Support set embeddings shape:  (5, 12, 12, 512)
Embeddings predict shape:  (5, 12, 12, 512)
```

Is any different between the both ways (as a parameter or with predict)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the predict function, the computation is done in batches. However, if you have small data then a function call is more suitable for faster execution.

This is the exact statement from Tensorflow Documentation:

> Computation is done in batches. This method is designed for
> performance in large scale inputs. For small amount of inputs that fit
> in one batch, directly using **call** is recommended for faster
> execution, e.g., model(x), or model(x, training=False)

See the complete documentation [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#predict)